# Extension of classical first law of thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, ideal-gas

The first law of thermodynamics is typically stated as conserving total energy in the context of a heat engine running on an ideal gas (or other gas whose equation of state is known). However, I read from Halliday-Resnick-Krane that in case centre of mass motion happens then it should also be taken into consideration. I have not seen this issue discussed much pretty much anywhere I’ve searched.

To mention a specific case where I am having some confusion, consider the so-called adiabatic atmosphere. We usually consider the standard $pV^\gamma=\text{constant}$ valid although the gas is moving under the influence of gravity and possesses centre of mass motion. One might be tempted to say that these “small” effects are ignored except the lapse rate calculation ($dT/dh$) takes gravity into account!

On further thinking maybe $dU$ and $dW$ cancel for conservative fields but I’ve not mentioned such a thing mentioned anywhere (someone on this site was giving an example of protostars but I didn’t exactly get the point). It’s also not obvious at all to me whether the effect of gravity will be considered if we simply take the pressure variation (the one used to derive barometric equation but here we’ll consider effect of changing temperature too) because the gas is not in a container on the ground whose external pressure is being changed but constantly moving upwards too.

Does there exist any standard formulation of the first law that avoids these issues (can we divide the energy parts into those that affect the gas’s equation of state and those that do not)?

Comment: A very interesting and instructive analysis is here http://actachemscand.org/pdf/acta_vol_03_p1208-1214.pdf The problem is fundamental in all external field cases, such as involving gravitational, electric, magnetic.

Comment: @hyportnex Thanks for the reference! I have seen topics like surface tension dealt in a similar manner to illustrate generality of thermodynamic methods but this is pretty different (apparently unknown in standard textbooks). Even when a related problem appeared in IPhO, this was not taken into consideration. From the view of kinetic theory it did look that temperature could be influenced by gravitation. I’m not well versed in statistical mechanics to do a rigorous analysis though.

Comment: When you write *the gas is moving under the influence of gravity and possesses centre of mass motion*, what situation are you considering? Something like fluxes of air in the atmosphere or what else?

Comment: @hyportnex Your link is interesting, but it addresses a different problem than the one mentioned in the Halliday-Resnick-Krane textbook.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I was considering a packet of air adiabatically rising in the atmosphere while the HRK book did not give any specific solved example and just mentioned it.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90  I hold my head down in shame but I do not have HRK... The article that is much more detailed on the very subject of changing center of mass and its effects is this http://actachemscand.org/pdf/acta_vol_31a_p0437-0443.pdf especially Fig 1 and Eqs, 15-24, 3rd part of a series of 4 articles you can find here http://actachemscand.org/author.php?aid=6272. Much more "technical" said here 10.1016/S0013-4686(96)00209-5 and 10.1016/S0013-4686(97)00214-4

Comment: You are wondering whether kinetic energy and potential energy should be included in the first law of thermodynamics.  Actually, they are included in the more complete form of the 1st law that does not neglect KE and PE.  See Moran et al, Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics and Smith and Van Ness, Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics>

Comment: I think the following paper (and some of its references) could help you to organize your ideas about the subject. In particular, section 6 of the paper is relevant to your question. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.2861

Comment: I think one thing that was confusing me was whether rising of a gas in gravitational field affects its temperature because although it lowers speed of the molecules, their speed remains same wrt each other. I guess it depends on the speed of the process. Initially it would not affect temperature but only centre of mass motion. But given enough time to thermalize, it would start affecting the temperature because the reduced vertical component would be compensated by the velocity in x,y directions.

Comment: This means the temperature might be different in different directions (apparently this is a thing) in the mean time before perfect equilibrium. So pressure would also be different in different directions? These are very small effects in comparison to change in internal energy due to temperature by the way, the ratio being $\approx 10^{-5}$ (by rough estimates for helium) so this might have been ignored for good in the Olympiad problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One should include the KE and PE terms in the first law. The way the temperature changes is probably as follows: initially an external systematic force like due to a potential causes a usual anisotropic effect as it would do on any object and then because it's a gas, it thermalises and this change in energy gets uniformly distributed. However, such effects are normally small and increase analytic complexity immense so mostly end up being neglected.